# Common Lisp: getting an error using readtable-case

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, gnu-common-lisp

When I enter this at the REPL prompt:

```
(setf (readtable-case *readtable*) :invert)
```

I get this error message:

```
Error in SETF [or a callee]: Cannot expand the SETF form (READTABLE-CASE
                                                          *READTABLE*).
```

Why do I get this error?

Comment: Which implementation are you using?

Comment: What'should the current package when you're evaluating this form? Any chance is not cl:readtable-case that you're writing?

Comment: I am using something called the LispIDE

Comment: What does `(format nil "~A ~A" (lisp-implementation-type) (lisp-implementation-version))` say? And what's the result of `(eq 'readtable-case 'cl:readtable-case)`? What's the current package, in which your `setf` form is read and evaluated?

Comment: (format nil "~A ~A" (lisp-implementation-type) (lisp-implementation-version)) says "Kyoto Common Lisp GCL 2.6.2". The result of (eq 'readtable-case 'cl:readtable-case) is T. What does this all mean please?

Comment: That `setf` expression may fail [if `*readtable*` is the standard readtable](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/02_aab.htm), only [obtainable through the `with-standard-io-syntax` macro](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_w_std_.htm).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `(format nil "~A ~A" (lisp-implementation-type) (lisp-implementation-version))` says "Kyoto Common Lisp GCL 2.6.2". The result of `(eq 'readtable-case 'cl:readtable-case)` is T. What does this all mean please?

The second expression means you're using the correct symbol. The first indicates which Lisp implementation you're using: That should be *GNU Common Lisp 2.6.2*

After some search I found this [message on the gcl-devel list](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.lisp.gcl.devel/4458) saying ...

> The problem appears to be this line:
>
> ```
> (setf (readtable-case *readtable*) readcase)
> ```
>
> in randomly-check-readability.  I'd recommend this as the next
> ansi issue to resolve, since it's blocking the tests.

... with a subject line "ansi-tests in 2.7.0".  The message is from 2004.

**Bottom line:** I guess you need <s>a more recent or even</s>* a different Lisp implementation.

(* as mentioned by Rainer Joswig the issue also affects the current 2.6.12 release)

---

I guess all major Lisp implementations support this. CLISP 2.49 [does](http://ideone.com/otXcib), SBCL and CCL probably do, as far as I know ECL does also.

Comment: Same problem in the lastest GCL release 2.6.12

Comment: Thank you @Daniel Jour! Would you recommend "a different Lisp implementation" please, one that supports readtable-case?